# Formatting text in alert window

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

guys i am having a text like this:

```
A: hi how are you.
B: I am fine thank you.
A: how is your mother.
B: she is fine.
```

i want in the same way to be displayed in the alert window irrespetive of text lenght.below is my alert window code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder bu = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
bu.setMessage(""+((Node) textFNListU.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
bu.setCancelable(true);
bu.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                bu.create().show();



+((Node) textFNListU.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim() ->this value i am fecthing from xml.
```

how to acheive this

Comment: how are you getting the alert window now, is all the text in one line?

Comment: yes vikram its all in one line

Comment: Use html to do it there's no \n there. http://jtomlinson.blogspot.com/2010/03/textview-and-html.html

Comment: @SergeyBenner where is the code in this link ...

Comment: @Goofy did you read it? there're examples with fromHtml() and setText()

Comment: @SergeyBenner i got it now will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
bu.setMessage(""+((Node) textFNListU.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim().replace(".",".\n"));
```

Comment: thanks its working but in some points i am having ?(question mark) eg:how are you? what to do for that?

Comment: the proper way would be to have the data in html format and use HTML.fromHtml("your html here");
for now: .replace(".",".\n").replace("?","?\n")